# Using lapply to generate a sentence for Markdown report from dynamic data

Tags: r, function, r-markdown, lapply

How do I generate a sentence like this:

```
Type A accounted for 10 (34%), type B for 8 (28%), and type C for 7 (24%), and type AB for 5 (17%).
```

From dynamic data like this:

```
Type <- c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A",
           "B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B",
           "C","C","C","C","C","C","C",
           "AB","AB","AB","AB","AB")
Type <- as.data.frame(Type)
```

I'm new to lapply functions applied to lists generated from unique variables but I'm a bit stuck with this one.

```
library(dplyr)

Type_list <- function(data, type) {

  data %>% 
  filter(Type == type) %>% 
  paste(type, length(Type$Type[Type$Type == x])) %>%
  paste0(((length(Type$Type[Type$Type == x]))/length(Type$Type)*100), "%")

}

i <- unique(Type$Type)

lapply(i, function(x) Type_list(Type, x))
```

Would an if statement be better than lapply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simpler solution for this. Just wrap a `table` statement in `prop.table`. This is what it's meant for.

```
prop.table(table(Type))
```

> ```
> Type
>         A        AB         B         C 
> 0.3103448 0.1724138 0.2758621 0.2413793
> ```

```
table(Type)
```

> ```
> Type
>  A AB  B  C 
>  9  5  8  7
> ```

Then your sentence:

```
pt <- prop.table(table(Type))

t  <- table(Type)


paste0("Type ", names(pt)[1], " accounted for ", t[1], " (",pt[1]*100,"%)...")
```

> [1] "Type A accounted for 9 (31.0344827586207%)..."

and so on. By the way, you can round the numbers if you want, like this `round(pt[1]*100)`, i.e.

```
paste0("Type ", names(pt)[1], " accounted for ", t[1], " (",round(pt[1]*100),"%)...")
```

> [1] "Type A accounted for 9 (31%)..."

Comment: Those are easy enough, now how do you take those values and insert them into this:

"Type A accounted for 10 (34%), type B for 8 (28%), and type C for 7 (24%), and type AB for 5 (17%)."

Comment: Yep, was just looking how to display counts. Thanks.

Comment: @Seth Sure no problem. I may have updated the answer after you looked at it. Use `t <- table(Type)` then `t[1]` for displaying the counts, where 1 is the relevant index number.